# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier while it's declared

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I get "DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier" on _totalSuppy and _balances. Could anyone help me figure this out?

**Parent contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import "../../utils/Context.sol";

contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata {
    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;
    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }
}
```

**Child contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract METoken is ERC20 {
    string public constant name = 'Mastering Ethereum Token';
    string public constant symbol = 'MET';
    uint8 public constant decimals = 2;
    uint constant _initial_supply = 2100000000;

    function METoken_settings() public {
        _totalSupply = _initial_supply;
        _balances[msg.sender] = _initial_supply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _initial_supply);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They’re not visible from `METoken` because they’re `private` to `ERC20`.